# How to describe plastic deformations in muscle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, material-science, biophysics

If someome does some sports intensively, the muscle deforms plastically; that can be felt a day after in the pain of the muscle that is stretched intensively.

I have learned plasticity theory in terms of continuum mechanics. This approach of plasticity theory uses yield surfaces and other assumptions. But I think plasticity theory can be formulated without these "engineering" constructions.

Furthermore, a muscle is an anisotropic material. Is it possible to describe plastic behavior of materials by the Liouville equation:

$\partial_tf(x,p,t) + v \partial_x f(x,p,t) + F\partial_p f(x,p,t)= 0$?

In the force function $F$ all interatomic interactions are encoded. Is Statistical mechanics an alternative to plasticity theory in continuum mechanics?

Comment: Is this a new theory? I've always thought muscle pain was caused by one of the several theories summarized here: https://themolecularcircus.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/your-body-the-whys-of-muscle-soreness/ as far as I've heard DOMS isn't caused by plastic deformation

Comment: As a bodybuilder, I can attest to the fact that muscle pain is not solely due to deformation; it is specifically due to trauma to muscle fibers (which is desired for growth) as well as development of lactic acid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a plastic model is the right one. It is well known that muscle microfiber rupture can be better explained by a [continuous damage model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damage_mechanics) (which by the way also uses damage surfaces, in a slightly different way than they are used in plasticity proper).

On the other hand, The self-regeneration of microfibers is another biological process that is far from being adequately resolved, although models of muscle growth have been proposed relating it to mechanical stress.